# How to deploy ArcGIS Engine (Standalone) with License Agreement?

Tags: arcgis-engine, visual-studio, license, standalone

I've completed a standalone app in ArcGIS Engine and in the process of deploying it, but I have a license agreement and supposed to add a licenseagreement.rtf file format in the properties menu while setting up in visual studio 2010.

Am I to create this file myself or am I able to find it?

Comment: Have you asked ESRI?

Comment: Do you have a license agreement? Are you trying to publish your application using ClickOnce or Instalshield LE?, because I have developed standalone applications with ArcGIS Engine, and I really do not remember that option. It seem something involved with deployment